# Programming Language Evaluation Strategies

Tags: programming-languages

Could you please explain differences between and definition of call by value, call by reference, call by name and call by need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Call by value

> Call-by-value evaluation is the **most common evaluation strategy**, used in languages as different as C and Scheme. In call-by-value, the **argument expression is evaluated**, and the resulting value is **bound to the corresponding variable in the function** (frequently by **copying the value into a new memory region**). If the function or procedure is able to assign values to its parameters, only its local copy is assigned — that is, anything passed into a function call is unchanged in the caller's scope when the function returns.

### Call by reference

> In call-by-reference evaluation (also referred to as **pass-by-reference**), a function **receives an implicit reference to a variable used as argument**, rather than a copy of its value. This typically means that **the function can modify (i.e. assign to) the variable used as argument—something that will be seen by its caller.** Call-by-reference can therefore be used to provide an additional channel of communication between the called function and the calling function. A call-by-reference language makes it more difficult for a programmer to track the effects of a function call, and may introduce subtle bugs.

#### differences

#### call by value example

> If data is passed by value, the data is copied from the variable used in for example main() to a variable used by the function. So if the data passed (that is stored in the function variable) is modified inside the function, the value is only changed in the variable used inside the function. Let’s take a look at a call by value example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call_by_value(int x) {
    printf("Inside call_by_value x = %d before adding 10.\n", x);
    x += 10;
    printf("Inside call_by_value x = %d after adding 10.\n", x);
}

int main() {
    int a=10;

    printf("a = %d before function call_by_value.\n", a);
    call_by_value(a);
    printf("a = %d after function call_by_value.\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this call by value code example will look like this:

```
a = 10 before function call_by_value.
Inside call_by_value x = 10 before adding 10.
Inside call_by_value x = 20 after adding 10.
a = 10 after function call_by_value.
```

#### call by reference example

> If data is passed by reference, a pointer to the data is copied instead of the actual variable as is done in a call by value. Because a pointer is copied, if the value at that pointers address is changed in the function, the value is also changed in main(). Let’s take a look at a code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call_by_reference(int *y) {
    printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d before adding 10.\n", *y);
    (*y) += 10;
    printf("Inside call_by_reference y = %d after adding 10.\n", *y);
}

int main() {
    int b=10;

    printf("b = %d before function call_by_reference.\n", b);
    call_by_reference(&b);
    printf("b = %d after function call_by_reference.\n", b);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this call by reference source code example will look like this:

```
b = 10 before function call_by_reference.
Inside call_by_reference y = 10 before adding 10.
Inside call_by_reference y = 20 after adding 10.
b = 20 after function call_by_reference.
```

#### when to use which

One advantage of the call by reference method is that it is using pointers, so there is no doubling of the memory used by the variables (as with the copy of the call by value method). This is of course great, lowering the memory footprint is always a good thing. So why don’t we just make all the parameters call by reference?

There are two reasons why this is not a good idea and that you (the programmer) need to choose between call by value and call by reference. The reason are: side effects and privacy. Unwanted side effects are usually caused by inadvertently changes that are made to a call by reference parameter. Also in most cases you want the data to be private and that someone calling a function only be able to change if you want it. So it is better to use a call by value by default and only use call by reference if data changes are expected.

### call by name

> In call-by-name evaluation, the arguments to a function are **not** evaluated **before the function is called** — rather, they are **substituted directly into the function body** (using capture-avoiding substitution) and then left to be evaluated whenever they appear in the function.

### call by need

> Lazy evaluation, or call-by-need is an evaluation strategy which delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed (non-strict evaluation) and which also avoids repeated evaluations

Comment: The call-by-reference example is bogus: C does not have call-by-reference.  What you demonstrated, is using pointers, which, in C, require explicit usage, and their values are passed by value.  A somewhat better example would be C++ which has the `&` type modifier for arguments of functions, or Pascal, with its `out` and `var` keywords or may be C# with `out` and `ref` etc.  Python, in which every instance of a class is passed by reference might be a good example too.